# Google In app Billing currency conversion issue

Tags: android, in-app-billing, currency

I was just facing some issues regarding google in app billing currency conversion. 
I am using an US account where the price set on dashboard for my product purchase is in USD.
Now, I am accessing my app in India. So the currency is getting converted into the local currency rate for all my product. 
Is there any provision to get the price amount in same currency like USD which set on the dashboard irrespective of the location. I am using google in app billing v3 API. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Guys, I am still waiting for any help.